# Why my C++ code got an error output when I use -O2?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Here is my code.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
struct Node {
    int x;
};
Node f(int A, int B) {
    if (A < 0) return {0};
    return {A / B + (A % B != 0)};
}
Node g(int C, int D) {
    if (C > 0) return {0};
    return {C / D + (C % D != 0)};
}
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    f(1, 1);
    Node t = g(-1, n);
    printf("%d\n", t.x);
}
```

Then I use: `g++-13 tmp.cpp -o tmp -O0`.
I input `2`, it should output `1`.
But `g++-13 tmp.cpp -o tmp -O2` I get `0`.

I think there is no undefined behavior. Why I get an wrong result?

OS: Linux x86-64 ubuntu23.10 6.5.0-21-generic
gcc version: >=9.2.0

Comment: If your optimized code gives diffent results your program has UB somewhere.

Comment: And that's here `(A % B != 0)`, read this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence and see if you can spot the bug yourself. (Consider the case where B is 0)

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aMKMPPosK)

Comment: Same problem even if we use `std::cin` and `std::cout`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9WoaMzTYv)

Comment: Looks like a gcc bug. If you remove the call `f(1,1)` you'll get the expected output.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I don't see how we get `B` = 0 from calling `f(1, 1)`.

Comment: @PepijnKramer so what's the problem with the operator precedence, exactly?

Comment: @PepijnKramer I don't see how calling `f(1,1)` should affect the output here.

Comment: @cafce25  but apparently it does only with -O2. Only in new g++ either

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Not in this case but it is a division by 0 when B is zero. Because % is evaluated befor !=

Comment: @cafce25 I agree I was a bit fast in responding.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yup, let's see what gcc maintainers in the bug report say. Let's wait for the confirmation there. I will add it in the answer when they do.

Comment: @user12002570 I think they optimize a little too aggresively, because of "potential" UB.  But yes lets see

Answer (score 5):

This is a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=113907). The inclusion of the statement `f(1,1)` seems to be the problem here. That is, the statement `f(1,1);` seems to affect the output of the program in optimization `-O2`. Without `f(1,1);` the output is `1` but with it the output is `0`.

Basically, the **call `f(1,1);`** here for input `2` **should not effect the output of the program** here since the program is well-formed.

Here is the newly submitted gcc bug report:

[GCC produces incorrect output with -O2](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=114290)

Old bug:

[ICU miscompiled since on x86 since r14-5109-ga291237b628f41](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=113907)

Comment: FWIW, I'm using g++ 13.2.0, and it resulted in the correct answer with `-O2`.

Comment: @Eljay So a regression it seems. With [gcc trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/foaGofsYb) we get the buggy output.

Comment: @Eljay not for me https://godbolt.org/z/1eb7Gxn1h It's the same from the trunk all the way down to 9.2.0.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI • Different default target architecture?  I'm on a 2017 era Intel Xeon W?  (I'm not sure how to get g++-13 to tell me what arch is targeting by default.)

Comment: @Eljay `-v` should show it.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI • `-v` did not show me the `-mcpu=cpu`  `-march=arch` or `-mtune=cpu` settings.  Ahh, `g++-13 -Q --help=target` worked:  `-march=x86-64 -mtune=core2` and lots of other things either enabled to some setting, disabled, or default.

Comment: For me even as early as `gcc 9.3` does that with no additional flags, `-march=skylake -mtune=skylake`. They claim this as as v.14 but. I saw some issues with "WET" code as early as gcc v.6 and `core2` but harder to reproduce as small snippets. Also clang-16 had a heartstroke with "bus error" in my configuration, not sure if I have just bad build

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what'sgoing onhere, but g++ generates obviously wrong code for `main` if `f` is used and everything gets inlined:

```
g(int, int):
        xor     eax, eax
        test    edi, edi
        jle     .L8
        ret
.L8:
        mov     eax, edi
        cdq
        idiv    esi
        ret
```

main() looks like this:

```
main:
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        lea     rsi, [rsp+12]
        call    __isoc99_scanf
        mov     eax, -1
        mov     edx, -1
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        idiv    DWORD PTR [rsp+12]
        mov     esi, eax
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
```